# Proper way of testing a NodeJS controller method using Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, controller, jestjs

JavaScript unit testing newbie here. I'm writing an API using NodeJS and Mongoose and after doing a little bit of research I ended up using Jest and Supertest for unit testing. For now I want to test a simple controller method that fetches all the records from the database.

This is my controller method:

```
const Gender = require("../models/gender");
exports.getMany = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const genders = await Gender.find();

    return res.status(200).json({
      data: genders,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(400).end();
  }
};
```

The tests I wrote so far work fine but I feel that I'm not doing it properly.

Here's the two test that I wrote for this method:

```
it("Get an empty array if there are no genders in the database", async (done) => {
  const response = await request.get("/api/v1/genders");

  expect(response.status).toBe(200);

  expect(response.body.data.length).toBe(0);

  done();
});

it("Get an array with existing genders in the database", async (done) => {
  const male = await request.post("/api/v1/genders").send({ name: "Male" });

  const female = await request
    .post("/api/v1/genders")
    .send({ name: "Female" });

  const response = await request.get("/api/v1/genders");

  expect(response.status).toBe(200);

  expect(response.body.data.length).toBe(2);

  expect(male.body.data.name).toBe("Male");

  expect(female.body.data.name).toBe("Female");

  done();
});
```

Am I doing it correctly?

Would it be more appropriate to call the `getMany()` method inside the test instead of accessing the route?

Thank you.

Comment: You can write tests that call getMany directly, but they'll look very different. What you're doing is an integration-level test of the API, but lower-level unit tests may also be appropriate. If you go in the unit test direction you should also extract a clearer service layer, so the transport layer is not involved in those tests. One issue with the second test is that it's unclear what you think you're testing - the last two assertions are on the return values from the posts, not related to the get you describe in the test title.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the service layer idea. For the second test I don't know exactly how to make the assertions... I want to make sure that if there's data in that collection, that data is retrieved correctly. That's why I'm also checking for the values, not only for the size of the array.

Comment: But you're checking the values from the earlier post requests, not the get that's the subject of the test. A simple step to help might be to not assign the returned post responses at all (i.e. get rid of `const male = ` and `const female = `), forcing yourself to use only the get response.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for tests like: the one you wrote and the other one you mentioned (calling the method directly without calling the route).

The advantage of your implementation is that it may catch issues in middlewares as well while calling the function directly will miss it.

The downside is that it's a bit slower because of the network call, so when multiplied by thousands of tests it gets to run the entire test-suite slower.

That's the main trade-off I can think of.

*Sidenote*

Different people call these tests in different names but I still didn't find a better name than E2E because, even if you call the function directly, it still uses a DB which means it cannot be considered as a classic unit-test. This is not an integration test as well because you're not testing the border of one unit of the code against another.

Comment: But I don't think that `integration` means that you must have another 3rd party. It could mean that you're just testing your components together.

Comment: @Cosmin that's how I've generally used integration too, with E2E being used for whole-system tests from the (web/mobile/whatever) client right through to persistence and other services.